# rsyslog send directory to remote host

Tags: linux, redhat, rsyslog

I'm having an issue with rsyslog sending remote logs:

I have a directory with some custom log files which don't have a consistent naming (random naming, they don't follow any pattern). I know about the imfile module to specify a file outside of /var/log.

Is there any chance that there is a rsyslog module capable of sending entire directories, instead of files, to a remote loghost?

If not, can rsyslog somehow process randomly named files, using some regex/wild-cards, instead of statically named files?